# Def mouseClicked() in draw not working, how do I fix it?

Tags: python, processing

I am making a dnd application for fun, the char class is what each character is, but I can't seem to get to work

I have tried commenting out sections of code, yet it seems to be a problem with the **init** function

This is my code:

```
global mouseY
global x
x = 0

chars =[]



def setup():
    global tsize 
    tsize = 50    


def draw():
    global x
    if x == 0:
        def mouseon(x,y,xs,ys):
            return(mouseX <= xs and mouseX >= x and mouseY <= ys and mouseY >= y)
        class char:
            def __init__(self, name, HP, img, CLASS, SIZE, id):
                self.xp = 0
                self.yp = 0
                self.SIZE = SIZE
                self.name = name
                self.HP = HP
                self.img = img
                self.CLASS = CLASS
                self.id = id
                self.Hover = False
                chars.append(self)

        dog = char("john", 100, "x.png", "archer", 50, 0)
        print("l") 
        x = 2

    else:
        fill(255)
        background(255)
        stroke(0)
        strokeWeight(1)
        for i in range(height/50):
            for j in range(width/50):
                rect(i*50,j*50,49.5,49.5)
        for i in chars:
            def mouseClicked():
                    if mouseon(i.xp,i.yp,i.xp+i.SIZE,i.yp+i.SIZE):
                        i.Hover = True
                        print('h')
                    else:
                        print("n")
                        i.Hover = False
            def mouseReleased():
                    print("o")
                    i.Hover = False
            if i.Hover:
                fill(0)
                rect(i.xp+1, i.yp+1, i.xp+i.SIZE+1, i.yp+i.SIZE+1)
            fill(0,255,0)
            strokeWeight(0)
            rect(i.xp, i.yp, i.xp+i.SIZE, i.yp+i.SIZE)
```

expected result:
when I press the mouse, I should get h or n printed to the console,  and when I release it, I should get o

Actual results:
nothing

EDIT:
to clarify, 
Draw is called once every frame 
setup once at the beginning 
mouseClicked when the mouse is clicked 
and mouseReleased when the mouse is released

Comment: For starters, you haven't called `draw`, so *nothing* in the definition of that function gets executed.

Comment: Draw is a function that is called every 1/60th of a second

Comment: @chepner No, this is [processing](https://processing.org/), `draw` and `setup` are called automatically.

Comment: `mouseClicked` and `mouseReleased ` are not called, because you didn't define them. You defined some functions with the same name in the scope of `char.__init__`, but the system "can't find" them, because you've to define functions with this names in global namespace.

Comment: Now you moved the functions from the scope of `char.__init__` to the scope of `draw`. They are still not in global name space. The have to be at the same level as `setup` and `draw`.

Comment: @Rabbid76 how would I do the i.size in it however? just I and it'll work itself out?

Comment: @JosephCatanzarit You've to traverse the`chars` in `mouseClicked`. Do `for i in chars:` in `mouseClicked`.

Comment: @Rabbid76 okay, that should work, and do it for both?

Comment: @JosephCatanzarit In `mouseReleased` you've to do something similar `for i in chars:` `i.Hover = False`

Comment: @Rabbid76 okay, that worked, but the mouseon function doesn't work anymore for it, as mouseon is out of scope

Comment: @JosephCatanzarit `mouseon` can be in global namespace, too.

Comment: @Rabbid76 no it can't, it uses mouseX and mouseY which must be in draw()

Answer (score 0):

okay, so I had to put the mouse clicked and released functions at the bottom and put the for loops in those, but it solved my problem

the updated code is

```py
global mouseX
global mouseY
global x
x = 0

chars =[]


def setup():
    global tsize 
    tsize = 50    


def draw():
    global x
    if x == 0:
        global mouseon
        def mouseon(x,y,xs,ys):
            return(mouseX <= xs and mouseX >= x and mouseY <= ys and mouseY >= y)
        class char:
            def __init__(self, name, HP, img, CLASS, SIZE, id):
                self.xp = 0
                self.yp = 0
                self.SIZE = SIZE
                self.name = name
                self.HP = HP
                self.img = img
                self.CLASS = CLASS
                self.id = id
                self.Hover = False
                chars.append(self)

        dog = char("john", 100, "x.png", "archer", 50, 0)
        print("l") 
        x = 2

    else:
        fill(255)
        background(255)
        stroke(0)
        strokeWeight(1)
        for i in range(height/50):
            for j in range(width/50):
                rect(i*50,j*50,49.5,49.5)
        for i in chars:
            if i.Hover:
                fill(0)
                rect(i.xp+1, i.yp+1, i.xp+i.SIZE+1, i.yp+i.SIZE+1)
            fill(0,255,0)
            strokeWeight(0)
            rect(i.xp, i.yp, i.xp+i.SIZE, i.yp+i.SIZE)

def mouseClicked():
    for i in chars:
        if mouseon(i.xp,i.yp,i.xp+i.SIZE,i.yp+i.SIZE):
            i.Hover = True
            print('h')
        else:
            print("n")
            i.Hover = False
def mouseReleased():
    for i in chars:
            print("o")
            i.Hover = False
```